# Store dropdown option value in database?

Tags: c#, sql, database, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a fictional website in ASP.NET MVC4 that's designed to simulate a private jet hire company ticket booking system. However, I am struggling a bit when it comes to implementing the features I want to have, one of which is using a dropdown menu to store data into another database

---

To give you a better idea of what I'm really aiming towards

- Users to log in to the website
- Go to the flights page
- Have a look at the flights
- Eventually go on to the make a booking page

Then

- Select their desired flight from a dropdown menu
- Input the number of tickets they want to purchase. (The dropdown is working but the reset isn't implemented)
- The user database should then check for the user's age (which is already
  stored in the database) is between 18 and 64

  - If they're outside of that range, an error message should appear
    and prevent them from booking a ticket.
  - If they're within that range, the amount of seats left should decrement by the number of tickets "purchased"

Also

- The booking page should prompt the user to log in if they haven't already done so.

---

This is where it gets really confusing for me.

I have two pages related to the flights:

- **Page 1** (`Flights.cshtml` - shows a table of the available flights): http://gyazo.com/2ab67e35bdd1967e4a24706e398ba759
- **Page 2** (`BookFlight` shows a dropdown menu, allowing the user to select the flight they want): http://gyazo.com/67948e5e8be82c72f7ee0914dfa9b5f6

(*Screenshot of the project files in solution explorer*)

[image]

Here are my relevant files related to the flights table (on page 1)

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/144ed06e1d4f2011161e

Page 2 reads from the list on page 1 and here's how it's done:

**View**:

```
@model List<Project_v3.Models.FlightsTable>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Book Flight | Open Airlines";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_MyLayout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Book A Flight</h2>

    <select id='SelectedFlight' name='SelectedFlight'>
        @foreach (var flight in Model)
        {
            <option value='@flight.FlightID'>@String.Format("{0} to {1}", flight.Departure, flight.Arrival)</option>
        }
    </select>
```

**Controller**:

```
    public ActionResult BookFlight()
    {
        using (var context = new FlightsDBEntities())
        {
            // Get all of the flights within your table
            var flights = context.FlightsTables.ToList();

            // Pass the flights to your View
            return View(flights);
        }
    }
```

---

**My Question is**

How do I make the data from the dropdown menu a field in another database table named 'Booking' for example? (I have not made this table yet). If that makes sense?

How do I take the information (from the dropdown) that the user has selected and store it with a press of a button? Is this even possible? Would anyone be able to show me a working example of this based on the code I listed above?

Comment: You apply the `[Authorize]` attribute to the method to ensure the user redirected to your login page if not authorized. You check the users age in the GET method (before you display the booking page) and redirect to an an error page if their age is invalid. Use view models and html helpers to generate your controls. I strongly suggest you go to the MVC site and work through the basic tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to create a model where you will store the item that will be selected.

```
public class BookingModel
{
    public string SelectedFlightId {get;set;}
    public List<SelectListItem> Flights {get;set;}
}
```

You need to modify the Action that make use of the new model.

```
public ActionResult BookFlight()
{
    using (var context = new FlightsDBEntities())
    {
        // Get all of the flights within your table
        var flights = context.FlightsTables.ToList();

        var booking = new BookingModel();
        booking.Flights = flights.Select(f => new SelectListItem
                            {
                                Text = String.Format("{0} to {1}", f.Departure, f.Arrival),
                                Value = f.FlightID.ToString()
                            }).ToList();
        return View(booking);
    }
}
```

Modify the View to make use of our new Model

```
@model Project_v3.Models.BookingModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Book Flight | Open Airlines";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_MyLayout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Book A Flight</h2>
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedFlightId, Model.Flights)
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

Create a new Action that have the same name as the first action, but put `HttpPost` attribute. In this action you will get `SelectedFlightId` after the form was submited

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult BookFlight(BookingModel booking)
{

    using (var context = new FlightsDBEntities())
    {

        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var flightId = Int32.Parse(booking.SelectedFlightId);
            var flight = context.FlightsTables.First(f => f.FlightID == flightId);

            var user = context.UsersTables.First(u => u.UserId == User.Identity.GetUserId());
            user.Flights.Add(flight)
            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        // repopulate again the flights (this can be cached and/or be refactored a under method)
        var flights = context.FlightsTables.ToList();
        booking.Flights = flights.Select(f => new SelectListItem
                            {
                                Text = String.Format("{0} to {1}", f.Departure, f.Arrival),
                                Value = f.FlightID.ToString()
                            }).ToList();
    }
    return View(booking);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I came across an issue with your solution. I created a new model by right clicking on Models and creating a new class then wrote the code as you posted however it's saying Error 11 The type or namespace name 'SelectedFlightId' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) A similar error goes for the List saying Expected 
class, delegate, enum, interface or struct. Please fix this issue in your answer by adding int to the selected flight id

Comment: In addition (I don't know how to fix this) I get an error in my controller where it says that `The name 'f' does not exist in the current context`. What's causing this to happen?

Comment: @BorisSmith thank you, i forgot to copy `int` when i posted the answer.

Comment: @BorisSmith i fixed the code where `f` appear please copy again the code.

Comment: Okay thank you very much, one last thing: `Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string'` Where it says `Value = f.FlightID`. What's causing this to happen?

Comment: @BorisSmith you have to add `f.FlightID.ToString()`

Comment: Yep, got it now, sorry for that. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74998/discussion-between-boris-smith-and-adricadar).